# How can I prove a coordinate ring is not isomorphic to a polynomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $Z$ be the plane curve $xy=1$. I would like to prove that $A(Z)$ is not isomorphic to a polynomial ring in one variable over $k$.

I'm already prove that the coordinate ring is $A(Z)=k[x,y]/(xy-1)$, but I couldn't finish the question.

I have a guess that $A(Z)\cong k[x,1/x]$, but I can't prove it formally yet and even I would I don't know what to say with this information.

I really need help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) The isomorphism $f:k[x,y]/(xy-1)\to k\left[x,\frac1x \right]$ is obtained from the morphism $F:k[x,y]\to k\left[x,\frac1x \right]:u(x,y) \mapsto u(x,\frac 1x)$ (which is clearly surjective) by passing to the quotient at the source by $ker(F)=(xy-1)$ (which last equality you have to check, of course).

2) In $k[x,1/x]$ the  non-constant element $x\in k[x,1/x]\setminus k$ is invertible, whereas in $k[x]$ only the elements in $k^*$, the nonzero constants, are invertible.
Hence  the $k$-algebras $k[x,1/x]$and $k[x]$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: Dear Georges, I am wondering if these is a more geometric reason as to why $\Bbb{A}^1$ and $\Bbb{A}^1 - \{0\}$ are not isomorphic. If these are over the complex numbers then sure, $\Bbb{C}$ and $\Bbb{C}- \{0\}$ are not isomorphic (for topological reasons).

Comment: Dear @fppf, yes there are other geometric reasons for non isomorphism: for example the number of points you have to add in order to obtain $\mathbb P^1$: respectively $1$ and $2$ for  $\mathbb A^1$ and $\mathbb A^1\setminus 0$, but these arguments  are more advanced. I like the above algebraic proof though, because of  its brutal and concise simplicity.

Comment: Dear user75086, it was a pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is right. $k[x,y]/(xy-1)\cong k[x,\frac1x]$ and an isomorphism is given by $$\varphi:k[x,y]/(xy-1)\to k\left[x,\frac1x \right]$$ by $\varphi(x)=x$ and $\varphi(y)=\frac1x$. You can show that $\varphi$ is indeed a ring homomorphism (precisely because you have the relation $xy=1$). It's also not hard to show that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism: it's obviously surjective and $\ker\varphi=\{0\}$.

**Edit** (Thanks to Georges for pointing this out):
So $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is not a field because $(xy-1)$ is not a maximal ideal. $(xy-1)\subset (x-1,y-1)$ which is a maximal ideal.

If you want to think about this in an algebraic geometry setting, think of the affine 2-space over $k$, which is just $\textrm{Spec}\ k[x,y]$. Assuming that $k$ is algebraically closed, the maximal ideals correspond to closed points and the curve $xy=1$ is obviously not a point.

Comment: Dear  Seunghee, it is not true that  $k[x,\frac 1x]$ is the fraction field of $k[x]$ nor that $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is a field: $x+1$ is not invertible in those (isomorphic) rings. Moreover it is not true that $(xy-1)$ is maximal in  $k[x,y]$ since we have a stict inclusion of proper ideals $(xy-1)\subsetneq (x-1,y-1) $, as shown by $xy-1=y\cdot(x-1)+1\cdot (y-1)$.

Comment: Dear Georges, thanks for pointing this out! I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Dear Seunghee, sorry for commenting again, but $Z$ **is** irreducible since the polynomial $xy-1\in k[x,y]$ is irreducible. The real picture of $Z$ is misleading because in the classical  topology (coming from the metric topology of $\mathbb R$) $Z$ indeed has two connected components, but this is no longer  true in the Zariski topology.

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out! I was also confused why I couldn't show $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ wasn't irreducible!

Comment: I don't get the last paragraph in your answer. What has $k[x,y]$ got to do with $k[x,y]/(xy- 1)$?